# Displaying all contents of all items continuously in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and i have 5 items in a group and each item is having 5-10 images, what i want is to display all images of all items continuously one after the other item. I am not getting how to start with this.now what i need is to display all images of all items dynamically..without user interaction. On page load first item gets highlighted and their contents should be displayed after that 2nd and so on for all items please help

Comment: by group , do you mean to say a folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use datalist. Please refer the link below.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-bind-images-from-folder-to.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested GridView or ListView Controls.

Eg.:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstvParent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGroupName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListView ID="lstvChild" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgPics" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```